# Dissolve polygons with road network gaps

Tags: gis, qgis, polygons

I am using QGIS and have a shapefile of the blocks in a large city, where each polygon is a particular streetblock. The city is divided into various sectors, and each block has information on its sector. I can easily classify the blocks by this attribute to visually inspect the shape of these sectors:

[image: sectors]

The issue is that the gaps between the blocks is the road network. I would like to dissolve all blocks in  the same sector into a contiguous polygon, but am unsure how to do this.

Does anyone know an easy way to "fill in" the gaps between the city blocks in order to make the `dissolve` work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve into multipart features based on the sectors, then extract nodes and try the concave hull plugin? Not sure how well the plugin works, though. Never used it.

Comment: I am able to successfully generate the convex hulls of these sectors, but the problem is that these hulls don't adequately depict the odd shapes of the sector boundaries, and places many of the blocks outside of these new polygons. Since I want to eventually measure the distance of the blocks to the boundary, this gives me negative distances